# How to properly upscale images using deconvolutions

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing, convolution, transposed-convolution

I have a dataset that has 32x32x3 images. However, I want to use models that were developed for 224x224x3 images, e.g. resnet. A common theme I see is that people resize 32x32x3 to 224x224x3, but this means a CNN is scanning large segments of identical and redundantly colored space. Conceptually, this is not ideal.

One idea is to put a few layers at the beginning of the network, allowing the network to learn a mapping from 32x32x3 to 224x224x3. I have read a little bit about deconvolutions and think that might be the answer.

What is a reasonable set of deconvolution layers to go from 32x32x3 to 224x224x3?

Answer (score 1):

Gaussian upsampling is one way to obtain soft, larger images http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture10.pdf . It basically consists of a simple resize followed by applying a softening convolution that makes the image smoother. Also, you don't necessarily need to go all the way up to 224. In many contexts, placing a small image in the middle of a black frame to achieve some pre-trained network's dimensions works well. You might try different balances between upsampling and extension with black pixels.

Lastly, what about another network? Pre-trained networks of many sizes and kinds are available online, for example here https://modelzoo.co/ . Hope that helps!

Comment: The black frame seems to give the same result as upscaling. I'll look into what a softening convolution might look like in this context. I think creating a parametric mapping from 32x32x3 to 224x224x3 might still be necessary.